# Andengine index out of bounds when removing sprite

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

I get an index out of bounds when detatching my sprite from the scene. Please note that i would like to remove the sprite from the Explosion class to keep my gameclass as "clean" as possible.

Here is where i create the sprite.

```
mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        if(something) {
            final Explosion expl = new Explosion(m.getX(), m.getY(), 
                getVertexBufferObjectManager(), false, 65);

            mScene.attachChild(expl);
        }
    }
});
```

Explosion class which removes sprite when animation is finished

```
public class Explosion extends AnimatedSprite {

private final Explosion self;

public Explosion(float pX, float pY, VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager, 
        boolean loopAnimation, long frameDurationEach) {
    super(pX, pY, regExplosion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);

    this.self = this;

    this.animate(frameDurationEach, loopAnimation, new IAnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStarted(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
             int pInitialLoopCount) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationLoopFinished(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
            int pRemainingLoopCount, int pInitialLoopCount) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationFrameChanged(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
            int pOldFrameIndex, int pNewFrameIndex) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationFinished(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite) {
            self.clearUpdateHandlers();
            self.detachSelf();
            self.dispose();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I kinda figured this out myself. I passed the engine as arguement to the Explosion which in turn ran the detach and dispose on the update thread. However, i do not like this solution as i dont think the explosion class should know of the engine, so if you got somehting better, please do tell :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yeah.It's a common problem when you detach sprite without inside the mEngine runOnUpdateThread.

So you need to write code inside

```
ResourceManager.getInstance().mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
         setIgnoreUpdate(true);
         self.clearUpdateHandlers();
         self.detachSelf();

        }
    });
```

or You can use main start up Activity UI thread which consists creation of Engine & scene. Both stands for same task. Like:

```
BaseActivity.instance.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do you work here

        }
    });
```

To clean up your game scene you should use **setIgnoreUpdate(true);** when detaching. Also, use **SetCullingEnabled(True)** when creating of your sprite.

For many sprite creation and detaching then at run time use generic pool.

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: This is better than what i had come up with. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm, the solutions seems to be working for GLES1 only. Do you have a similar solution for GLES2?